# Can DuckDuckGo be given the correct modified date?

Tags: discussion, search, data-dump

This is something I've noticed just recently, but DuckDuckGo has put "7 days ago" next to a few Stack Overflow hits today. But when I click through they are e.g., "Asked 6 years, 3 months ago  Modified 6 years, 3 months ago "  or "Asked 9 years, 1 month ago
Modified 1 year, 2 months ago" (the latter on superuser.com, so not just stackoverflow.com).

Maybe "7 days" means it last fetched data from the site then?

It made me wonder if there is an HTTP header or meta data that the modified date can be written to. Or if that already exists, we just need to point DuckDuckGo engineers at the documentation for it.

**UPDATE** An example (taken from comments). It now shows 31st May 2023, which is 8 days ago as I take this screenshot. Also notice that the first of the three has no date on it.

[image]

The 3 links shown there are:

- [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)   ( Asked 14 years, 4 months ago  Modified 6 months ago )
- [Comparing strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833538/comparing-strings-in-java)  ( Asked 13 years, 6 months ago  Modified 13 years, 6 months ago )
- [Comparing Strings in Java (greater of lesser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103065/comparing-strings-in-java-greater-of-lesser)  ( Asked 2 years, 1 month ago  Modified 2 years, 1 month ago )

Comment: A Screenshot maybe could be "handy", or a Link at least... // But tja...!, I've always found those relative Dates a bit useless and always confusing, (I keep some Tabs open for days/weeks sometimes, then "*3 hours/days ago*" quickly doesn't mean anything anymore), I prefer exact Dates/Timestamps, we are all "clever enough" to know the current Date/Time and make the "Calculation" ourselves...

Comment: "Maybe "7 days" means it last fetched data from the site then?" - you need to research that yourself, it depends on the search engine. And also, from a quick search, I can see that many links say "7 days". It seems to be the case. Also what does this question have to do with the tag [data-dump]? Please read the meaning of the tag before using it.

Comment: Actually, this issue seems to be due to the new code of conduct banner. Which was introduced 7 days ago. I am sure this is the issue.

Comment: @chivracq Yes, me too, and most datestamps in the search results are actual dates. Example person This is my research: I don't know how DuckDuckGo and StackOverflow work together, but I wondered if they might use those data-dumps, and are not doing old-fashioned spidering. Please suggest better tags if you know some.

Comment: Search engines usually spider sites. The date could come from any number of fields, such as the last modified header, to some sort of date field in the response. In this case, it's apparently coming from the `data-campaign` attribute on the announcement banner div. SO has no control, and mostly likely, no partnership with Duck Duck Go, and trying to tailor their site to manage the date scrape per site engine is probably a huge headache

Comment: @DarrenCook, but would duckduckgo actually download stack overflow data dumps? There are millions of websites on the internet that they may want to crawl. In my opinion, it would be easier for them to just do the normal way. But remember, that's just my opinion.

Comment: I haven't voted on this question, but it would help to see an example of exactly what you're referring to.  Ideally, as was suggested above, via a link (and a screenshot, as the contents of the link are likely to change over time).

Comment: Example: https://duckduckgo.com/?va=v&t=ha&q=Stack+overflow+java+string+compare&ia=web, second link says "7 days ago", but is to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833538/comparing-strings-in-java, which is from a long time ago.

Comment: Qt now "logically" closed as "needs details or clarity", was to expect... To improve the Qt: 1 or 2 Screenshot(s) needed, + its/their corresponding Link(s) + Explanation/clarification about selecting the `[data-dump]` Tag included in the Qt (and not as a Comment) + adding the `[search]` Tag + maybe some other "relevant" Tags are maybe missing, and I'm not sure if `[discussion]` is really relevant...

Comment: There's [rich data](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results/result/r%2Fq-and-a?id=eZQsrYQxkkeZAkrz_cNvGg) for every page, but search engines tend to ignore that and instead scrape the page.

Comment: DDG is a proxy for Bing. Any data issues would be with them.

Comment: @OrangeDog That's a bit of a simplification; Bing is the partner for bulk results, but DDG also run their own crawler for specialised purposes, and integrate various specialised feeds for "Instant Answers". It's *probably* Bing's data at fault here, though.

Comment: I absolutely hate relative dates, in StackOverflow and everywhere else. If two comments were made "about 5 years ago" I want to know whether they were separated by 5 minutes or 5 months.

Comment: Hover over the timestamp, and you'll see *exactly* when the event occurred in the tooltip, @MichaelKay.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes I know. Hovering over two different dates/times that both say "about 5 years ago" to see how far apart they occurred is not my idea of usability.